# How to calculate the correct width for a fluid-width nav menu?

Tags: jquery, css, submenu, responsiveness

Take a look at this design inspiration menu: http://theblondeabroad.com

How can I properly calculate the width of this kind of responsive submenu using jQuery especially when browser is on resize? Plus giving an absolute position(left and top) from the main container so that it remains on the center?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the submenu

Comment: http://theblondeabroad.com/


Those with images inside the submenu. I like to calculate the container of that submenu responsively. So from 1100px container downward on resize.

Answer (score 1):

The `width()` method of **jQuery** will give you the calculated width of an element:

```
$(function(){
  $('#menu li:has("ul")').each(function(){
    alert($(this).width());
  });
});
```

check out this link for further reading

[Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var window_width = $(this).width();
   //and then set the width of the dropdown accordingly
   $('#yourdropdown').css('width',window_width/4+"px");//or something that you require
});
```

Hope this helps!